# How to use Head JS with all enqueued scripts?

Tags: javascript, performance, wp-enqueue-script

I want to load head js first and then all enqueued scripts into it's function. Like so...

```
<script src=">/js/head.load.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
head.js("/path/to/jquery.js", "/google/analytics.js", "/js/site.js", function() {

   // all done

});
</script>
```

How would I do this?

For those that don't know HeadJS is the 2.30KB script that speeds up, simplifies and modernizes your site...

http://headjs.com/

Comment: I don't think you need this. Just put your scripts before `</body>` and they will load after the document is rendered...

Comment: Putting your files at the bottom will most likely break stuff as alot plugins put inline scripts in the head.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be forewarned that not all plugins/themes use enqueue. When I first started dealing with all the JavaScripts and CSS files outputed I just hooked into the enqueued files. This resulted in me only getting 2 out of 10 JavaScript files and 1 out of 3 CSS files.

Here is some quick PoCs. Neither tested but meant to put you in the right direction, if you can code. Once I get home I'll whack together something more fitting and functional.

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts','head_files');
function head_files(){

    global $wp_scripts, $auto_compress_scripts;

    print 'print out head.js';  

    $queue = $wp_scripts->queue;
        $wp_scripts->all_deps($queue);
        $to_do = $wp_scripts->to_do;
    $headArray = array();
        foreach ($to_do as $key => $handle) {
            $src = $wp_scripts->registered[$handle]->src;
        $headArray[] = $src;
    }

    print 'print out head.js("'.implode("'",$headArray.'")';
}
```

(Basically swiped most of the code from [JS & CSS Script Optimizer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/js-css-script-optimizer/))

```
add_filter('wpsupercache_buffer', 'head_files' );
function head_files($buffer){
    if ( $fileType == "js" ){
            preg_match_all('~<script.*(type="["\']text/javascript["\'].*)?src=["\'](.*)["\'].*(type=["\']text/javascript["\'].*)?></script>~iU',$content,$matches);
            $headArray = $matches[2];
    }


    print 'print out head.js';  

    print 'print out head.js("'.implode("'",$headArray.'")';
    return $buffer;
}
```

Using WP Super Cache output buffering.

Comment: nice, but he should use that plugin instead of head.js in my opinion. it has the option to combine all js, compress it and move it in the footer

Comment: As stated before, moving stuff to the footer automatically on WordPress install leads to broken inline JavaScript.

Comment: I don't understand. Why would the footer javascript break? Head.js here does exactly the same thing (loading js after DOM is loaded).

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'm trying to do to integrate head.js:

i put this code in my template `functions.php` file

```
define('THEME', get_bloginfo('template_url'), true);
define('THEME_JS', THEME . '/js/', true);

add_action('wp_print_scripts','head_js_files');
function head_js_files()
{
    if (is_admin()) return; //to preserve the admin

        global $wp_scripts;

    $in_queue = $wp_scripts->queue;

    if(!empty($in_queue))
    {
        $scripts = array();
        foreach($in_queue as $script)
        {

            $src = $wp_scripts->registered[$script]->src;
            $src = ( (preg_match('/^(http|https)\:\/\//', $src)) ? '' : get_bloginfo('url') ) . $src;
            $scripts[] = '{' . $script . ':"' . $src . '"}';
        }

        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"".THEME_JS."head.js\"></script>\n";
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">head.js(\n". implode(",\n", $scripts). "\n);</script>\n";
    }

    $wp_scripts->queue = array();
}
```

It outputs something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">head.js(
    {jquery:"/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"},
    {jquery_lastfm:"http://localhost/lucianomammino/wp-content/plugins/lastfm-recent-tracks-widget/js/jquery.lastfm.js"},
    {nav:"http://localhost/lucianomammino/wp-content/themes/lmtheme/js/jquery.dropdown.js"}
);</script>
```

Notice that it also uses script labeling that could be really useful sometimes to identify what (and when) scripts are loaded.

Comment: try testing this with plugins that call `wp_print_scripts` after <head> :)

Comment: What kind of plugins do so?

Comment: here's one: http://www.gravityforms.com (also your function doesn't handle localized js)

Comment: @one-trick-pony gravity forms is a paid plugin... i obviously prefer to try a free one! In the meanwhile i fixed my code to be compatible also with localized js...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out this plugin (or at least look at the code in it):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/headjs-loader/

It does a regex on the output before it printed to the screen, so it works even with scripts that were not enqueued.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for this. I'm using yepnope instead of head.js, but the theory's pretty much the same.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40325/9802

I hope it helps, and let me know if you have any comments on that other thread.