# Script loaders vs wp_enqueue_script

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

My Wordpress theme has a lot of .js scripts running and it takes plenty of time to load them all one by one. I would love to use a script loader like [HeadJS](http://headjs.com/) or 
[yepnopejs](http://yepnopejs.com/) to speed things up.

But... what about wp_enqueue_script? I'm using it to load every single script (and I believe that's the BEST & ONLY way to go?).

Won't loading scripts using script loader instead of wp_enqueue_script create any conflicts with plugins, widgets etc.?

What about enqueuing the script loader itself?

Comment: Is this your personal theme/site, or a public theme you're developing?

Comment: Both, I guess! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If this is for your personal blog only, then just use a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) that minifies and concatenates JS.
- If it's for a theme you're building, then if the scripts are custom, or small & unlikely to be used by other plugins, merge them all into a single .js file, and load it in the footer.

  A more hardcore method would be to pick up registered scripts from the `$wp_scripts` global, unregister them all, and concatenate them into one file (or load them with headjs, whatever way you want to go). Here are [some ideas](http://codepad.org/MJMU4ccK) if you go this way...

Answer (score 0):

Building off of the code that @OneTrickPony provided, I came up with a solution for this that works pretty well for me. I posted it as an answer to another similar question here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40325/9802

I hope it helps someone, and if you see any issues please leave me a comment on that other thread.